# HTML/CSS email not formatting correctly on Windows in Outlook 10 or 13

Tags: html, css, windows, email, outlook

I'm still pretty new to coding in general. I'm working off of a template that my predecessor made for this email, and it's rendering correctly in all email clients on Macs, but on Windows machines, Outlook 10 and Outlook 13 make the email margins shift to the left, and the body content extend incorrectly. I've identified where the problem is, and it's in the body of the email after the headline (the headline and footers are formatted properly, but the body is not.)

```
<div class="headline" style="max-width:650px;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="650px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0;" >
    <![endif]-->

     <!--[if (gte mso 14)|(IE)]>
        <table width="650px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0;" >
    <![endif]-->

     <!--[if (gte mso 15)|(IE)]>
        <table width="650px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0;" >
    <![endif]-->

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0; Margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:650px; background-color: #ffffff;">
       <tr>
            <td align="left" style="width: 100%; font-size:0;">
             <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="90%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->

                 <!--[if (gte mso 14)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="650px" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="90%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->

                 <!--[if (gte mso 15)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="650px" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="90%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->
```

[image: Here is a screenshot (zoomed out for security) of what the problem looks like:]

**Update**

Now my code reads:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100% "style="border-spacing:0;">
                   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" > 

                        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="90%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->

                 <!--[if (gte mso 14)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="100%" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0; Margin:0 auto;"> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="100%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->

                 <!--[if (gte mso 15)|(IE)]>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;"> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="100%" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->
```

And it's better, but there are still an issue with too much margin on the right, and it's more pronounced in Outlook 2013: 
[image]

Comment: HTML email? _Welcome to hell._

Comment: Yep. Where I work, we use ExactTarget, so it's kind of our only option.

Comment: I believe you have to make 2 tables one for the 100% and the inner for the content

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. If you get a second, do you know why everything has to have those nested tables when building html emails?